# Naturaly view for rotated objects

Tags: objects, 3d-view, shortcut, scene, axis

I create a car and place it in a scene. I rotated it to adapted it to the road.
Now when I want to edit the car to modify it, it's dificult because the car is rotated.
Is there a way to view it like it was before I place it in the scene.
I would like to use the keys '1', '3' and '7' to work with the car naturally.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my awful english.

Comment: In addition to the linked answer (which consist on pressing Shift + numpad number, you can also Alt D > Link Duplicate your object, reset the rotation of the copy and work on it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is what I'm looking for :D